# Find a basis for the polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the vector space $P_2$ of all real polynomials of degree at most $2$ and the subset $W = \{p(t)\in P_2\mid p(3) = 0\}$ of $P_2$.

Find a basis for $W$. Justify your answer. You may use the following fact: for $p(t)$ to be in $W$ it must factor to a polynomial of the form $(t−3)(at + b)$, where $a$ and $b$ are real numbers.

**Solution: (6 points)**

\begin{align*}
W &= \left\{p(t) \in P_2\mid p(3) = 0\right\}\\
&= \left\{(t−3)(at + b)\mid a,b \in \mathbb{R}\right\}\\
&= \left\{a(t^2 −3t) + b(t−3)\mid a,b \in \mathbb{R}\right\}\\
&= \text{span}\left\{t^2 −3t, t−3\right\}.
\end{align*}

Since $t^2−3t$ is not a scalar multiple of $t−3$ the set $\left\{t^2−3t, t−3\right\}$ is linearly independent, and it spans $W$, so $\left\{t^2 −3t, t−3\right\}$ is a basis for $W$.

I don't understand how to use "the following fact". The answer I got was

$$x=s\begin{bmatrix}-3& 1& 0\end{bmatrix}+t\begin{bmatrix}-9& 0& 1\end{bmatrix}$$

but this is not linearly independent. I got it by taking the coefficients of a $2$ degree polynomial an putting them in a matrix and getting the $1$ row with leading $1$ and then the other $2$ columns were $s$ and $t$.

Comment: You do not define $W$ before using it.

Comment: @Harry49 I think $W$ is the set of polynomials of the form $(t-3)(at+b)$.

Comment: If you wish that someone helps you, you should write questions in a correct English and use Mathjax. *Bacis? Pollynimial? Colloms?*

Comment: I suppose "the following fact" is the definition of $W$...

Comment: I think the original question reads, "Find a basis for the subspace $W = \{p(t) \in P_2 | p(3)=0\}.$"  Then the fact they are allowed to use is the fundamental theorem of algebra.

Comment: I agree with @B.Goddard and have edited accordigly

Comment: I think you are saying that a basis for $W$ is $[-3\,1\,0]$ and $[-9\,0\,1]$. But that's a category mistake; the elements of $W$ are polynomials not row vectors. If by $[-3\,1\,0]$ and $[-9\,0\,1]$ you really mean $-3+t$ and $-9+t^2$, then that's right; they do form a basis.